# Getting Access Denied after receiving valid session id

Tags: python, session, websocket, tornado

I have a working python/tk program that runs a cgi script based on user selection.  I'm working to cut this down to a small script that just focuses on one particular cgi script.  It appears to be getting the session id correctly but when I launch the browser I keep getting "access denied".  As the other program works I not expecting any issues from the website.  Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
If I use a debugger and set a breakpoint on the line **print url** the url printed in the console, as seen below, does work.  I now know the session id token is good.

Also if I **step into** the webbrowser function and then **step over** after that the script also works.

Here is my code.

```
import json
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado import gen
import tornado.ioloop
import webbrowser
from struct import *

request_id = 71
ip_address = "10.22.4.14"


# ************************************************
# Procedure to open websocket and get session id
# ***********************************************
@gen.coroutine
def open_ws(ip, username, password):
    global client
    global request_id
    global session_id

    ws_url = "ws://" + ip + ":7011/"

    try:
        client = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(ws_url, None, None, 5, None, None)
        # print("websocket %s open" % ws_url)
    except error:
        exit()

    # Send Mercury login request
    JSON = '{"requests":[{"request_id": %s, "login":{"username": "%s","password": "%s"}}]}' % (str(request_id), username, password)

    client.write_message(JSON)
    results = yield client.read_message()
    # print("msg is %s" % results)

    # Parse the response of login request to get the error code
    parsed_json = json.loads(results)
    err_code = parsed_json['responses'][0]['request_response']['result']['err_code']

    if 0 == err_code:
        # Parse the response of get_command_result to get the session id
        session_id = parsed_json['responses'][0]['request_response']['login']['session_id']
        # print("login succeeded - session id: %s" % session_id)
    else:
        print("login failed")
    # error_exit(err_code)


def get_token():
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: open_ws(ip_address, 'admin', 'admin'))
    return session_id

session_id = get_token()
print "Token is " + session_id

url = "http://" + ip_address + "/scripts/dostuff.cgi?session=" + session_id
print url  # add breakpoint here

# launch browser
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Console output:

```
Token is 7zNSZX9liaUDFFN0ijn-LWQ8
http://10.222.4.14/scripts/dostuff.cgi?session=7zNSZX9liaUDFFN0ijn-LWQ8
```

Comment: Is the webserver expecting a cookie along with a session id?  Or does it expect the session id to be delivered as a cookie instead of a query string?

Comment: No.  This is the exact format used in the python/tk app which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  The script was ending therefore closing the socket before the browser had a chance to respond to the request